# DataTables display multiple rows as one / hyperlink

Tags: jquery, hyperlink, datatables, server-side

[image]

I am using exactly this example : http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/server_side/server_side.html

Now I don't want to have 3 columns "Artits, Title, Version" instead I want to have one column "Name" where the 3 are shown together.

I have no idea how to do this...

Also I wanted to add a hyperlink to the "Name" that contains the "setid" but this code is not so easy to understand for me.

This here is not working :

```
var oTable = $('#example').dataTable({
    "bServerSide": true,
    "sAjaxSource": "serversideTests.php",
    "sAjaxDataProp": "aaData",
    "bProcessing": true,
    "aoColumns": [{
      "mData": "setid"
    }, {
      "mData": "beatmapid",
      "sClass": "hidden"
    }, {
      "mData": "expectedPP"
    }, {
      "mData": "perfectPP"
    }, {
      "mData": "Artist",
      "sClass": "hidden"
    }, {
      "mData": "Title",
      "sClass": "hidden"
    }, {
      "mData": "Version",
      "sClass": "hidden"
    }, {
      "mData": null,
      "mRender": function(data, type, full) {
        return full['Artist'] + '-' +
            full['Title'] + '[' + full['Version'] + ']' +
          '<br><a href=/' + 'osu.ppy.sh/d/' + full['setid'] + '>' + 'Download' + '</a>';
      }
    }, {
      "mData": "StarDifficulty"
    }, {
      "mData": "ApproachRate"
    }, {
      "mData": "BPM"
    }, {
      "mData": "length"
    }]
});
```

With indexes

```
 var oTable = $('#example').dataTable({
    "bServerSide": true,
    "sAjaxSource": "serversideTests.php",
    "sAjaxDataProp": "aaData",
    "bProcessing": true,
    "aoColumns": [{
      "mData": [0],
      "sClass" : "hidden"
    }, {
      "mData": [1]
    }, {
      "mData": [2]
    }, {
      "mData": [3]
    }, {
      "mData": [4],
      "sClass": "hidden"
    }, {
      "mData": [5],
      "sClass": "hidden"
    }, {
      "mData": [6],
      "sClass": "hidden"
    }, {
      "mData": null,
      "mRender": function(data, type, full) {
        return full[4] + '-' +
            full[5] + '[' + full[6] + ']' +
          '<br><a href=/' + 'osu.ppy.sh/d/' + full[1] + '>' + 'Download' + '</a>';
      }
    }, {
      "mData": [7]
    }, {
      "mData": [8]
    }, {
      "mData": [9]
    }, {
      "mData": [10]
    }, {
      "mData": [11]
    }]
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it with this code:

```
    var oTable = $('#myDataTable').dataTable({
    "bServerSide": true,
    "sAjaxSource": "records.json",
    "sAjaxDataProp": "aaData",
    "bProcessing": true,
    "aoColumns": [{
      "mData": "id",
      "sWidth": "5%"
    }, {
      "mData": "title",
      "sClass": "hidden"
    }, {
      "mData": "link",
      "sClass": "hidden"
    }, {
      "mData": "artist",
      "sClass": "hidden"
    }, {
      "mData": "image",
      "sWidth": "10%",
      "mRender": function(data, type, full) {
        return '<img src="' + data + '"></img>';
      }
    }, {
      "mData": null,
      "mRender": function(data, type, full) {
        return '<b>' + full['title'] + '</b><br>' +
          '<i>' + full['artist'] + '</i><br>' +
          '<a class="btn btn-info btn-sm" href=#/' + full['link'] + '>' + 'Download' + '</a>';
      }
    }, {
      "mData": "status",
      "sWidth": "2%"
    }]
    })
```

Note that several rows have a **sClass** `hidden` which hides the row from display but keeps the data intact.

The actual Name column has `null data` but a rendering function that collects the entries from the hidden rows and renders a html snippet.

Have a look at this [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/g35cRd3QCSXKBDVt20Xt?p=preview) to see it working.

**UPDATE 2:**

If you are not returning key:value pairs from your json call, you have to use indexes (starting at 0):

```
    "aoColumns": [{
      "mData": [0],
      "sClass": "hidden"
    }, {
      "mData": [1]
    }, {
      "mData": [2]
    }, {
      "mData": [3]
    }, {
      "mData": [4],
      "sClass": "hidden"
    }, {
      "mData": [5],
      "sClass": "hidden"
    }, {
      "mData": [6],
      "sClass": "hidden"
    }, {
      "mData": null,
      "mRender": function(data, type, full) {
        return full[4] + '-' +
          full[5] + '[' + full[6] + ']' +
          '<br><a href=/' + 'osu.ppy.sh/d/' + full[0] + '>' + 'Download' + '</a>';
      }
    }, {
      "mData": [7]
    }, {
      "mData": [8]
    }, {
      "mData": [9]
    }, {
      "mData": [10]
    }]
```

Look at the (once again) updated [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/V0hT6yITpbvoFS4gAm6Y?p=preview)

Comment: Thank you!!! I modified the code a bit and it's not working, could you take a look at it? I edited it in my question.

Comment: Are you getting undefineds? The need to see some lines of your ajax data returned from the server. Else try to describe what exactly is not working.

Comment: http://ppaddict.com/serversideTests.php

Those are over 5000 rows of data so I'm not sure if you want see them, your browser might crash.
It 

What I get is this : http://ppaddict.com/tests.php

Comment: Just as I thought, you are not returning key:value pairs from your ajax call. In this case you have to use numeric indices to address the data. See my updated answer. If you can do this, change your server sided code to return proper key:value pairs. Makes the whole stuff more readable.

Comment: I'm using the server-side example from DataTables, I don't really know how to add proper key:value pairs.

It's still not working, sorry..

Comment: I'm at home now. Please wait until tomorrow.

Comment: What I noticed: You are returning sEcho:0 from your server call, this should be at least 1. Next you have one field to much in aoColums. Take out the last one. This is the issue with indices, you always have a miscount. Been there, too! Try to fetch your db stuff with mysql_fetch_assoc, then you should have key value pairs. Look at the updated update in my answer and at the according plunker. Since I can't do crosside requests I had to strip down your serverdata a bit. Note that pagination, sorting and filtering doesn't work this way.